# Google Play Games Services can't register class (Unity)

Tags: c#, android, plugins, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I use GPGS for Unity (this)
When I launch my app on phone i have this (and no activity from plugin):

```
D/GamesUnitySDK(12145): Performing Android initialization of the GPG SDK
E/GamesNativeSDK(12145): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/nearby/Nearby: an exception occurred.  
E/GamesNativeSDK(12145): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/nearby/connection/AppIdentifier: an exception occurred. 
E/GamesNativeSDK(12145): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/nearby/connection/AppMetadata: an exception occurred.  
E/GamesNativeSDK(12145): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/nearby/connection/Connections: an exception occurred. 
E/GamesNativeSDK(12145): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/nearby/connection/Connections$StartAdvertisingResult: an exception occurred.  
I/Unity   (12145): InvalidOperationException: There was an error creating a GameServices object. Check for log errors from GamesNativeSDK  
I/Unity   (12145):   at GooglePlayGames.Native.PInvoke.GameServicesBuilder.Build (GooglePlayGames.Native.PInvoke.PlatformConfiguration configRef) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0  
I/Unity   (12145):   at GooglePlayGames.Native.NativeClient.InitializeGameServices () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0  
I/Unity   (12145):   at GooglePlayGames.Native.NativeClient.Authenticate (System.Action 1 callback, Boolean silent) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0  
I/Unity   (12145):   at GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform.Authenticate (System.Action 1 callback, Boolean silent) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0  
I/Unity   (12145):   at GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform.Authenticate (System.Action 1 callback) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0  
I/Unity   (12145):   at GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesLocalUser.Authenticate (System.Action`1 callback) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0   
I/Unity   (12145):   at GooglePlayServiceController.Login () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0  
I/Unity   (12145):   at GooglePlayServiceController.Start () [0x00000] in <filename unknown
```

For Init use thin in `Awake`:

```
PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder()
        .EnableSavedGames()
        .WithInvitationDelegate((invitation, shouldAutoAccept) => {})
        .WithMatchDelegate((match, shouldAutoLaunch) => {})
        .Build();
    PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
    PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
```

And this in `Start` for login:

```
Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) =>
    {
    });
```

In google I find some actions to resolve this problem but it doesn't work (last version plugin, last version `android sdk`, my account is tester in `Developer Console`).

Someone can help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Happened the same to me and after reading this thread (https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/506) the solution was:

- Update the Android SDK Google Play Services package to a version >=r23 (under the extras category)
- Go to Window | Google Play Games | Setup | Android Setup... and click on Setup (this will update the local copy of the library)
- Rebuild

Be very careful if you are also using Google Play Games for Unity plugin because you may encounter this problem:
https://github.com/googleanalytics/google-analytics-plugin-for-unity/issues/51